# NSCalendarUnitSecond returning zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdate, nscalendar

I have this method returning a string. But the seconds value is always zero. What am I doing wrong?

```
-(NSString*)secondsBetweenDate:(NSDate*)startDate andDate:(NSDate*)endDate {

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    unsigned int unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;

    NSDateComponents *difference = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:startDate  toDate:endDate  options:0];

    long hour = [difference hour];
    long min = [difference minute];
    long sec = [difference second];
    NSLog(@"Hour: %ld Min: %ld Sec: %ld", hour, min, sec);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld:%02ld", hour, min, sec];
}
```

Comment: What are your dates? There is an infinite amount of dates that would yield zero seconds difference if you ask for h, m and s.

Comment: This is a counter to show the time between two dates. Every second I call this routine and update a label with the new time.

Comment: timeToAlertBox.text = [self secondsBetweenDate:sarWatchStartTime andDate:sarWatchEndTime]; the sarWatchEndTime is a time 15 mintes in the future from sarWatchStartTime.

Comment: Put a NSLog in there and log `startDate` and `endDate` and show us the result. For me your method works correct if the dates are correct. E.g.: `[self secondsBetweenDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-99999] andDate:[NSDate date]];` yields `Hour: 27 Min: 46 Sec: 39`

Comment: sarWatchStartTime: 23:18:05 sarWatchEndTime 23:33:05

Comment: And what did you expect? There are exactly 0 Hours, 15 Minutes and 0 Seconds between 23:18:05 and 23:33:05. 5 seconds from endDate minus 5 seconds from startDate is a difference of exactly 0 seconds

Comment: If you want to show the time related to the current time you have to set startDate OR endDate to `[NSDate date]` (i.e. NOW). You are just calculating the difference between two static dates.

Comment: Ha. Thanks. :-) The obvious errors are always the hardest to spot.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch if he wants the seconds, that won't fix the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the default NSDate difference calculations?
Returns an NSTimeInterval which is in seconds:

> typedef double NSTimeInterval;  Description   Used to specify a time
>   interval, in seconds.

Operation is:

```
[aDate timeIntervalSinceDate:anotherDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. If you use the dates that actually differ in their seconds value it yields the expected results.

```
[self secondsBetweenDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-99999] andDate:[NSDate date]];
```

logs:

```
Hour: 27 Min: 46 Sec: 39
```

And 99999 Seconds is 27*60*60 +46*60 +39

---

In our discussion in the comments we discovered that you had more of a conceptional problem. If you need to show a countdown or stopwatch type string you have to use the current time as one of the date parameters.

So if you want to show the time that has passed since a specific date (like a stop watch) you use:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
string = [self secondsBetweenDate:yourStartDate andDate:now];
```

If you want to show the time until a specific date (like a countdown) you use:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
string = [self secondsBetweenDate:now andDate:yourEndDate];
```

---

Btw: If you are only targetting iOS 8 and later you can use `NSDateComponentsFormatter` to format your date

```
NSDateComponentsFormatter *df = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
df.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStylePositional;
df.allowedUnits =  NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
NSString *dateString = [df stringFromDate:startDate toDate:[NSDate date]];
```